# Quotient a group by a proper subgroup.

Tags: group-theory

If you have a group $G$ and a proper subgroup $H$ inside of the group. Then is $H$ a proper subgroup of the quotient group $G/H$?

Comment: No, never. They're **basically** different mathematical identities. It could though be that $\;H\;$ is *isomorphic* to a subgroup of $\;G/H\;$

Comment: $H$ isn't even a sub **set**.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is an honest question!

Comment: It seems to be the answers that have the downvotes rather than the question - presumably because they just add to the confusion!

Comment: @user1729, it may be a reaction to the OP's accepting a wrong answer...funny, but some downvote for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to be a subgroup of a group, one must first be a subset. However, $H$ is not a subgroup of $G/H$ for any normal subgroup $H$ because $G/H$ contains as its elements cosets in $G$. For instance $H$ is the identity of $G/H$ because $H$ is the class of the identity $e\in G$. The identity in $H$ is $e$ though and so if it was a subgroup then it would share the same identity as $G/H$. This is not the case.

It is possible for $H$ to be *isomorphic* to a proper subgroup of $G/H$ and this is a more interesting question. The easiest example is if $H$ is the trivial subgroup generated by the identity. In this case $G/\langle e\rangle=\{\{g\}\mid g\in G\}$ and so the subgroup $\{\{e\}\}\in G/\langle e\rangle$ is isomorphic to the subgroup $\{e\}$ in $G$. (note the double brackets in the notation used for the trivial subgroup in $G/\langle e\rangle$. It's important).

Answer (score 5):

No, $H$ is an *element* of $G/H$, your question is like asking whether $2$ is a subgroup of $\mathbf{Z}$.

Answer (score -2):

You have the natural mapping:

$$v\colon G \rightarrow G/H$$

If H is a normal subgroup, then $G/H$ (set of cosets) is a group. There you can identify $H$ with the $0$ element.

Comment: Again, not even a subset and this, more than clearing things out, can easily confuse the OP, which already accepted a wrong "answer".

Comment: This doesn't address the problem.

Comment: Your answer that a trivial subgroup is isomorphic to another trivial subgroup is at least trivial.

Comment: Maybe the questioner scrambled something. From the definition it is clear that a subgroup of G can not be a subgroup of G/H. But with the right construction H is the neutral element of G/H

Comment: Trivial but informative. The OP is having a problem, it seems, with identifying what the elements in a quotient group are. I emphasised that even though the trivial subgroups of both groups are isomorphic, they have different elements and so are not equal.